# abstract table from java in C#

Tags: c#, java, swing, datagridview

Is possible create an Abstract table in C# like in java?
For exemple, in java i had an abstract class that **extends javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel** and with this i can easily create my own custom tables...
But my real question is if there is any table in C# where i can add an element of an array for every row, for exemple, in java i had this code:

```
public void fillTable(LinkedList<Message> tabel) {

    messageModel.clear();
    LinkedList<Message> messages;
    if (tabel == null) {
        messages = AppData.getInstance().messages;
    } else {
        messages = tabel;

    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= messages.size() - 1; i++) {
        messageModel.addRow(messages.get(i));

    }

    Tabel.setModel(messageModel);
}
```

I have read something about DataGridView but I'm not sure if is that what im looking for...
Thank you in advance!

Edit as request:
So, i have this in java [image] and i want to convert this to C#... every row in the table is an object of an array. I have an abstract class for an abstract table and then, with that abstract class i have have to create a model for a table and i get my table... This is my code of the model table if you want to see:

```
public class ModeloParaMensagem extends AbstractModeloTable1<Mensagem>{

public ModeloParaMensagem(){
    super(new String[] {"ID", "Activo", "Mensagem","Numero","Data"});
}



@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    Object valueAt = null;
    
    Mensagem row = getDados().get(rowIndex);
    
    
    switch (columnIndex){
        case 0:
            valueAt = row.getId();
            break;
        case 1:
            valueAt = row.getChecked();
            break;
        case 2:
            valueAt = row.getMsg();
            break;
        case 3:
            valueAt = row.getNumero();
            break;
        case 4:
            valueAt = row.getData();
            break;
    }
    return valueAt;
}
}
```

this class extends of my abstract table (the generic one) and then I use the super for configure the table columns...
Thank you again for the help.

Comment: Please describe what you need with more detail. It is a UI (visual) element that you're looking for? is it a 'data' structure? Please be specific.

Comment: Yes, what is it that you need? Do you need to insert data into a table? It looks to me like you are trying to get data out of the table using the row and column index.

Comment: I need to insert data into the table and manage that data by the column index, since it will be an array entry i will be able to work with the array using the table indez, for exemple, row number 4 will have the index 3 in my array the same object with all the information that is preset in the table will be messages[3]